# How to send my activity to background and resume?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I want to load data from Internet.

While loading data I show a loading indicator. What I want to do when pressing back, I cancel the loading indicator via `onCancelEvent()`. I want to my activity to continue in background, so that the last activity is shown to front.

I don't want to finish() and start the last activity as all the data is shown in that, which will be loaded again if recreated.

Can any one help?

Comment: I wish I could help, but I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase and ask exactly what you want it to do?

Comment: Thanks for your time. In short. I am on a activity. And if in the layout of activity a button click I want to send my activity to background (same as like back button pressed). So my question is simple how to send my activity to background without finishing the activity so that it will be no more visible to user.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand; I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to switch the order of the current background and the previous background. To do this, you can start the previous activity and use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPreviousActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

So if you have tasks A, B, C and task C calls startActivity() with activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the activity stack, with the resulting order A, C, B, which is what you were asking for.

See [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: Thanks its woks. But I have to implements things in more details.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```