# Android: restore previous application to foreground

Tags: android

At times I will launch one of my app's activities, either using something like an `IntentFilter` or a `Service` etc. Once the user has done what he needs to in my app's `Activity` for the time being, I want the app to resume whichever app/activity the user was in prior to the service bringing my app to the foreground.

The only way I can think of doing this is as per [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246703/getting-current-running-application), determine the foreground app's package name before bringing my app/Activity to the foreground. Then, when I want resume that app to the foreground, I launch the application given its package name, [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422758/start-application-knowing-package-name).

But there are some problems: firstly it needs the `GET_TASKS` permission. Secondly, I would need to determine the foreground application before my Activity launches. It would be handy to determine the previous app/activity **after** mine is launched (Or better yet, just restore to it without having to know anything about it)

Are there alternatives to my method above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `finish` your application and as I know android OS will resume previous opened application.

Also look at this question [How to bring an activity to foreground (top of stack)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack) maybe it will help you.

Comment: finish() forces my app to be destroyed, I would like to leave it up to Android whether it should just be paused, stopped or destroyed, as it isn't just being called for a result. As for the link to that question, you need to know what Activity was previously up?

Comment: This link helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911101/how-to-send-my-activity-to-background-and-resume