# Use onStop for unbinding service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an `Activity` and i want to close it without calling `onDestroy()`. So I use `onStop();` which looks like

```
@Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        try{
            unbindService(mServerConn);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I runs the code but the activity is still visible on the screen

Can you help me to hide it?
Thanks!

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911101/how-to-send-my-activity-to-background-and-resume

Comment: Im a bit confused. Do you want to close the activity (i.e. pop it off the stack and go back or go to another activity) or do you want to stop the service when the activity ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of `onStop()` is not correct in that situation. If you need to close activity use `finish()`.

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
openStartingPoint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
finish();
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `onStop()` but you can go about like this:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

This will call `onStop()` and lead you to the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

> `onStop()` will be called when your activity is not visible on
>   foreground to user.
>
> So, if your activity is currently visible to user, then it means
>   `onStop()` is yet to be called from **Android Framework**

Your approach is correct. You are **unbinding** from service in `onStop()` which is right way.

I think you application will run correct and there is no need of modification

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `System.exit(0);` to close it without calling `onDestroy().`

Comment: but ,i think this only way to exit  without calling onDestroy() & onStop()

Comment: It is not correct to stop the ```JVM``` this way. Resources may stay unreleased, states can be lost, etc...